# automatically save outlook attachment - error

Tags: vba, outlook

I am getting the following error on the script below, I'm trying to set up a script that will run when activated by an outlook rule (i.e. Apply this rule after message arrives; from person@email.com; run a script) and save any attachments to a particular folder.

runtime error '91' Object variable With block variable not set

the error is against 'For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments'

```
Public Sub script()
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.attachment
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim dateFormat

    dateFormat = Format(SentOn, "yymmdd ")    
    saveFolder = "C:\temp"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If objAtt.Size > 5200 Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
            Set objAtt = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the **itm** object. Try to define it as a parameter to a method in the following way:

```
 Public Sub script(itm as Outlook.MailItem)
```

Comment: `itm` is declared, even if it is declared in the method as parameter does not need a Dim keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not a VBA developer. The **itm** object is not assigned/initialized for further using.

Comment: Eugene is right, you need to *initialize* the itm variable. There is no line of code that sets that variable "set itm = ..."

Comment: thanks everyone, this seems to be working now, will save me a ton of time!